# APScheduler update database only once

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I'm trying to get APScheduler to update in my Flask app the Postgresql database every 5 minutes, but the database is only updated the first time, all subsequent times the changes are not saved. APScheduler itself works correctly, and if the function of updating the database is replaced with the function of displaying text, then everything works correctly every time.

In my app im using Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:name@localhost/name'
```

The APScheduler code looks like this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(func=update, trigger='interval', minutes=5)
sched.start()
```

The database update function looks like this:

```
def update():
    for i in data:
        for row in Names.query:
            if row.id == i['id']:
                row.name = i['name']
                row.gender = i['gender']
                row.age = i['age']
    db.session.commit()
```

In the logs, APScheduler always works successfully. I also looked at the Postgresql logs, where I found this phrase: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

I suspect it might be the database engine and sessions, but I haven't found the instructions I need to implement within the Flask-SQLAlchemy package.

Versions of pacages:

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.17
APScheduler==3.6.3
```

db Model:

```
class Names(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['name', 'age']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(40))
    age = db.Column(db.Numeric)
   
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Names %r>' % self.id
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add to your question: SQLAlchemy version, the session setup code and  where `Names.query` is coming from?

Comment: I edited my question and added what you asked there. It looks like my sessions are not configured in any way, only SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is located in config.py, and only this construction is located in the app.py file: db = SQLAlchemy (app). I tried adding @ app.before_request and @ app.after_request, but it didn't give any results and now they are not in the code.

Comment: Where is `data` coming from and what is the format. And what do you expect to happen with data in the `Names` table.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Data comes from a private API in this format:
`[{'id': '1', 'name': 'john', 'age': '28'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'frank', 'age': '30'}]`. The function should update the data in the table. In manual mode, it does it correctly and I can access the API every minute - it has no limits. Problem only when upgrading from APScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what the problem is. APScheduler somehow caches the contents of a variable the first time it is used and then only uses that value.
Before the function, I have the following code:

```
request = requests.get('https://privateapi')
data = request.json()
```

Then the function takes data from data:

```
def update():
    for i in data:
        for row in Names.query:
            if row.id == i['id']:
                row.name = i['name']
                row.gender = i['gender']
                row.age = i['age']
    db.session.commit()
```

According to the Flask-SQLAlchemy logs, the data is written to the database successfully. I tried adding to the print (data) function so that every 5 minutes it would show me the contents of the data variable and I saw that its contents were not updated.

It turns out that the data is written to the database, but with the same values, so I don't see its update.

Then I tried shortening the request path and not saving its content to a variable:

```
def update():
    for i in requests.get('https://privateapi').json():
        for row in Names.query:
            if row.id == i['id']:
                row.name = i['name']
                row.gender = i['gender']
                row.age = i['age']
    db.session.commit()
```

But here again nothing has changed.

UPDATE:
I solved this problem by removing the data variable at the end of the function:

```
def update():
    name = requests.get('https://privateapi').json()
    for i in name:
        for row in Names.query:
            if row.id == i['id']:
                row.name = i['name']
                row.gender = i['gender']
                row.age = i['age']
    del name
    db.session.commit()
```